# Contar el numero de veces que pasa por un jframe

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield, jbutton, jlabel

Estoy creando un juego de peguntas y respuestas en java. No tengo bien una idea de como puedo hacer para contar las veces que pasar por un Jframeform. Mi juego está divido en 2 partes una clase Lógica en la cual abro el archivo de Excel del  cual obtengo las preguntas y las respuestas, en esa misma clase valido la repuesta. En la otra clase Juego tengo la interface  gráfica y los botones con un Countdown.

Clase Juego:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import spartacus20.coddy.logica.Logica;
import javax.swing.Timer;
/**
 *
 * @author veget
 */
public class Juegos extends javax.swing.JFrame{

 
    
    Timer tiempo;
    private int count = 60; 
    int intentos; 
    int suma; 
    public Juegos() {
        initComponents(); 
        intentos ++; 
    }
   
    Logica log = new Logica(); 
 
    
          
         
    int aleatorio = log.generaNumeroAleatorio(0, log.nfilas());
    String pregunta = log.juego(aleatorio, 0);
    String A = log.juego(aleatorio, 1); 
    String B = log.juego(aleatorio, 2); 
    String C = log.juego(aleatorio, 3); 
    String D = log.juego(aleatorio, 4); 
    String respuesta = log.juego(aleatorio, 5); 
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        b_a = new javax.swing.JButton();
        texto_pregunta = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        b_b = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b_d = new javax.swing.JButton();
        b_c = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        texto_tiempo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

        /*
        b_a.setText("<User Code>");
        */

        if(log.isNumero(A) == true){

            b_a.setText(A.substring(0, A.length() - 2));

        }else{

            b_a.setText(A);

        }
        b_a.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                b_aActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        texto_pregunta.setText(pregunta);

        /*
        b_b.setText("<User Code>");
        */

        if(log.isNumero(B) == true){

            b_b.setText(B.substring(0, B.length() - 2));

        }else{

            b_b.setText(B);

        }

        /*
        b_d.setText("<User Code>");
        */

        if(log.isNumero(B) == true){

            b_d.setText(D.substring(0, D.length() - 2));

        }else{

            b_d.setText(D);

        }

        /*
        b_c.setText("<User Code>");
        */

        if(log.isNumero(C) == true){

            b_c.setText(C.substring(0, C.length() - 2));

        }else{

            b_c.setText(C);

        }

        /*
        texto_tiempo.setText(count);
        */
        tiempo = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                count --;
                texto_tiempo.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                if(count == 0){

                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }

            }

        });
        tiempo.start();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(texto_tiempo)
                .addGap(24, 24, 24))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(texto_tiempo)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(b_a)
                    .addComponent(b_b))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 92, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(b_c, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(b_d, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(62, 62, 62))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                        .addComponent(texto_pregunta))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                .addComponent(texto_pregunta)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(b_a)
                    .addComponent(b_c))
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(b_b)
                    .addComponent(b_d))
                .addGap(80, 80, 80))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void b_aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
      
       toBack(); 
       System.out.println(intentos);
       setVisible(false);
       log.isCorrecta(A, respuesta);
       
    }                                   

    public static void main(String args[]) {
     
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juegos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juegos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juegos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Juegos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              
                 new Juegos().setVisible(true);    
             
               
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton b_a;
    private javax.swing.JButton b_b;
    private javax.swing.JButton b_c;
    private javax.swing.JButton b_d;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel texto_pregunta;
    private javax.swing.JLabel texto_tiempo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Clase Lógica:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import spartacus20.coddy.ventanas.Archivos;
import spartacus20.coddy.ventanas.Correcta;
import spartacus20.coddy.ventanas.Incorrecto; 
import spartacus20.coddy.ventanas.Juegos;


public class Logica{

    private boolean Correcta; 
        
    private int puntos = 0;
    private int intentos;

    Archivos fc = new Archivos();    

  
    File file = new File("Perguntas.xlsx");
    
    public int getPuntos() {
        return puntos;
    }

  

    public int getIntentos() {
        return intentos;
    }

    public void setIntentos(int intentos) {
        this.intentos = intentos;
    }
    

    
    public static boolean isNumero(String opc){
        
        try{
            
            Float.parseFloat(opc); 
            
            return true; 
            
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            
            return false;
            
        }
 
    }
    
    public int generaNumeroAleatorio(int minimo, int maximo) {

            int num = (int) (Math.random() * (minimo - (maximo + 1)) + (maximo + 1));
            return num;
        }

    public String juego(int filas, int celda) {
        
                List datos_celda = new ArrayList(); 
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            
            
            
            FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream(file);
            
            //Estoy abriendo el archivo de excel. 
            XSSFWorkbook excelarchivo = new XSSFWorkbook(fileinput);
            
            
            //Estoy obteniendo el libro 1 
            XSSFSheet libroexcel = excelarchivo.getSheetAt(0);
            
            //Creamos un iterador(objeto que me permite recorrer un contenedor) que me recorra el librodeexcel
            
            Iterator contenedor_fila = libroexcel.rowIterator();
            
        
            while(contenedor_fila.hasNext()) {
                //Obtenemos las filas. 
                XSSFRow fila = (XSSFRow) contenedor_fila.next();
                
                Iterator<?> contenedor = fila.cellIterator();
                
                List<XSSFCell> contenido_contenedor = new ArrayList<XSSFCell>();
                
                while(contenedor.hasNext()) {
                    
                    //Obtenemos los contenidos de la celda 
                    XSSFCell contenido_celda = (XSSFCell) contenedor.next();
                    
                    contenido_contenedor.add(contenido_celda);
                    
                    
                }
                
                datos_celda.add(contenido_contenedor); 
                
                
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error al encontrar el archivo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        }else{
            System.out.print("El archivo no fue encontrado");
        }
                
        List lista_temporal = (List) datos_celda.get(filas);
        
        XSSFCell celdas = (XSSFCell) lista_temporal.get(celda); 
        
        String valor = celdas.toString();
        
        
        return valor; 
    }
    
    
    public int nfilas(){
            List datos_celda = new ArrayList(); 
            
            if(file.exists()){
                try {
            
            FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream(file);
            
            //Estoy abriendo el archivo de excel. 
            XSSFWorkbook excelarchivo = new XSSFWorkbook(fileinput);
            
            
            //Estoy obteniendo el libro 1 
            XSSFSheet libroexcel = excelarchivo.getSheetAt(0);
            
            //Creamos un iterador(objeto que me permite recorrer un contenedor) que me recorra el librodeexcel
            
            Iterator contenedor_fila = libroexcel.rowIterator();
            
        
            while(contenedor_fila.hasNext()) {
                //Obtenemos las filas. 
                XSSFRow fila = (XSSFRow) contenedor_fila.next();
                
                Iterator<?> contenedor = fila.cellIterator();
                
                List<XSSFCell> contenido_contenedor = new ArrayList<XSSFCell>();
                
                while(contenedor.hasNext()) {
                    
                    //Obtenemos los contenidos de la celda 
                    XSSFCell contenido_celda = (XSSFCell) contenedor.next();
                    
                    contenido_contenedor.add(contenido_celda);
                    
                    
                }
                
                datos_celda.add(contenido_contenedor); 
                
                
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error al encontrar el archivo");
            System.out.print("Intente verificar los datos del archivo"); 
                        e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
             
              }else{
                System.out.print("El archivo no existe"); 
            }
             
            int aleatorio =  datos_celda.size();
           
            return aleatorio;
            
            
        }   
    

    public boolean isCorrecta(String opc, String respuesta){
        
        if(opc.equals(respuesta)){
            
            puntos +=50; 
            System.out.println(puntos);
            Correcta bien = new Correcta(); 
            bien.setVisible(true);
            Correcta = true; 
            return Correcta; 
            
        }else{
           
            puntos -=50; 
            Incorrecto mal = new Incorrecto(); 
            mal.setVisible(true);
            return Correcta; 
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

No se en donde exactamente tengo que hacer para contar las veces que pasar por el Juego

Answer (score 0):

He simplificado un poco mas mi codigo dividiendo las preguntas y las respuestas pero aun no se como hacer el contador y en donde implementarlo para que funcione

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;




public class Preguntas {
    
   private String pregunta; 
   private String respuesta; 
   private int puntos= 0;
   private int intentos=1; 
   private String opcion; 
   
   public String getOpcion(int fila, int celda){
       
       Logica log = new Logica();
       
       List dato = log.cargarFichero(); 
       
       List datos_temporales = (List) dato.get(fila); 
       
       XSSFCell celdas = (XSSFCell) datos_temporales.get(celda); 
       
       String opcion = celdas.toString(); 
       
       return opcion; 
   }
   
   
   
   public String  getPregunta(int filas){
       
       Logica log = new Logica(); 
     
       
      
       
       List datos_celda =  log.cargarFichero();
       
       List lista_temporal = (List) datos_celda.get(filas);
        
        XSSFCell celdas = (XSSFCell) lista_temporal.get(0); 
        
        String pregunta = celdas.toString();
        
        
        return  pregunta; 
       
       
   } 
   
    
   public String getRespuesta(int filas){
       
       Logica log = new Logica(); 
       
       
       List datos_celda = log.cargarFichero(); 
       
       
            List lista_temporal = (List) datos_celda.get(filas);
        
        XSSFCell celdas = (XSSFCell) lista_temporal.get(5); 
        
        String respuesta = celdas.toString();
        
        
        return  respuesta; 
       
 
   }

    public int getPuntos() {
        return puntos;
    }

    public int getIntentos() {
        return intentos;
    }
```